# "Network connection was interrupted" error with shared Access database

Tags: ms-access

We have an Access database with a split front/back end. The back end resides on a Samba 4.1.6 share with around 15-20 users. Frequently the database will popup with the error "Network access has been interrupted". Obviously this is not ideal.

When we move the back-end to a Windows home server share the issues do not persist, so as far as I'm aware this rules out any hardware issues within the network itself.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue? Or anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Yes. The Access Database Engine is designed to work with "real" Windows file sharing and Samba – or at least some versions of Samba – apparently do not implement all of the low-level features of the SMB protocol that are needed for the Access Database Engine to work reliably.

(ref: [Corrupt Microsoft Access MDB Causes - Samba](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruption/causessamba.htm))

Comment: A MySQL back-end on a non-Windows server will not have the same issue because Samba will not be involved (assuming that each user has their own local copy of the Access front-end, which is absolutely required for reliable multi-user operation).